# is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to write a prolog code to find [Bezout constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) for gcd.

I tried this code :

`gcdCoef(A,B,X,Y) :- Z is A*X + B*Y, gcd(A,B,Z).`

but when I Execute the query `?- gcdCoef(12,20,M,N).` it gives me the error :

`"is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"`

Note that gcd works properly : `gcd(A,B,Z) means gcd(A,B) = Z`

what should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: There is an infinite number of possibilities to satisfy your formula. You need to provide hard numbers as arguments for calculations, because prolog can't deal with things it has no way of inferring from the available data. The calculation part is almost directly put into a separate module, which to my knowledge is straight up c++, so it behaves differently from the rest of prolog.

Comment: Try `gcdCoef(A,B,X,Y, Z) :- Z is A*X + B*Y.` with the query `?- gcdCoef(12,20,5,10, Z), nl, write(Z).`

Comment: `is/2` *requires* that all variables in the second argument be instantiated with numeric values. It's purpose is to evaluate the expression and result in a specific value. If there are variables, it cannot evaluate it. You cannot use `is/2` to solve for variables in the expression. Try using CLP(FD). Then you can use `A*X + B*Y #= Z`.